# Add a static prefix to urls generated in webpack

Tags: webpack

I want to add a prefix ("/static/") to every static url generated by webpack.  However I want the generated bundle to ignore this, so app.js and staticfiles all end up in the same directory.  The file loader allows specifying a prefix with `?name=static/[name].[ext]` but my bundle then comes within a `static/` dir in the output.

I want to do this because I am serving my app from tornado, so every path needs some kind of prefix or I can't serve the homepage

Webpack Config

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        ...
        {test: /\.(jpg|ttf|html|eot|woff2?|svg)$/, loader: "file?name=static/[hash].[ext]"},
    ]
},
```

Tornado config

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[
        (r'/', MainHandler),
        (r'/socket', SocketHandler),
        (r'/utilization', UtilizationHandler)
    ],
    autoreload=True,
    debug=False,
    template_path=os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'templates'),
    static_path=os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'public'),
    static_url_prefix='/static/'
)
```

The `static_url_prefix` set above is actually the default.  I can't set it to empty or the root path goes to tornado's `staticHandler` instead of my `mainHandler`.

Comment: Did you tried `output.publicPath` parameter (docs - https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath ) ?

Comment: Thank you for that, it was indeed exactly what I needed.  I have a follow up question though, see my comment on the accepted answer in case you are able to help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In webpack.config.js set the publicPath option.

```
output: {
    path: "/home/proj/public/assets",
    publicPath: "/static/"
}
```

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath

Comment: Thanks to you and Bob Sponge, that does do what I was looking for.  Obligatory gripe about the docs not using the word "prefix" in that segment.

One major issue is that it seems to break the devServer, is there a way to only set the option on build?

Comment: I solved this by adding `--output-public-path='/static/'` to the `npm run build` command in package.json, and not using `publicPath` in webpack.config.js