# How to have your app served as "/path" with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to have my app served at localhost:8080/bub, but, using the following webpack config, when at localhost:8080/bub I get `Cannot GET /bub`

I'm using `devServer.publicPath`, but it seems as it is not read.

What must I change in the config?

Here it is

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
    node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
    plugins: [
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
};

var aConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "a",
    entry: "./js/bub/app",
    output: {
       path: "/tmp/a",
       filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
     contentBase: '/tmp/a',
     publicPath: '/bub/',
     hot: true
    }
});


module.exports = [
    aConfig
];
```

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911597/add-a-static-prefix-to-urls-generated-in-webpack

Comment: I tried adding output.publicPath: '/bub/' but nothing changed, and, however, if I understand correclty, that publicPath has another use

Comment: use historyApiFallback: true in devServer options

Comment: I'm sorry but even this doesn't work, neither with /bub nor with /bub/

Comment: ok, the config was already fine. I hadn't understood the real effect of devserver.publicPath, I believed that it remapped / to /bub, but it is not so. It serves the bundle from the publicPath dir, and localhost:8080/bub/bundle.js is indeed found